# Как определить кнопку, которая была нажата, если кнопки находятся в QButtonGroup?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton, qbuttongroup

Имеется множество кнопок, которые находятся в `QButtonGroup`.

Как узнать какая именно кнопка была нажата из этой группы?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QButtonGroup.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QButtonGroup.checkedButton

Answer (score 0):

Сигнал [**buttonClicked**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) отправляет кнопку, которая была нажата:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(view)
    
    group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
    
    for i in range(10):
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"button-{i}")
        layout.addWidget(button)
        group.addButton(button)
    view.show()

    def handle_button_clicked(button):
        print(button, button.text())

    group.buttonClicked.connect(handle_button_clicked)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @DeochanDeochan что не так?

Answer (score -1):

По описанию задачи начал бы искать ответ в таких примерах:

```
1)self.sender()
2)self.findChild(type(self.sender()), self.sender().objectName())
3)self.findChildren(type(self.sender()))
4)self.children()
```